# How to execute multiple powershell Commands in Synchronous using C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, synchronous

How to execute multiple powershell Commands in Synchronous using C#?

Comment: Do you mean "How do I call Powershell scripts synchronously from a C# application?"?

Comment: Side note: gogreen, when updating question please remove  tags from title and "thank you notes"/"I'm new to this town"/"plz give me teh codez" from your post.

Comment: Yes, that will work too! But let's say I have a list which contains multiple commands (Get-Process, Get-Culture, Dir etc..) and how can I execute the list of commands synchronously using c#. Please let me know if that can be achievable.

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to execute several commands from C# code; just look at the "related" links.